# No indentation in tabular caption

Tags: tables, captions, koma-script, wrapfigure

I have the problem, that the second and further lines in a caption under a table (also graphics) is indented. I don't want an indentation.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, bibtotoc, liststotoc]{scrbook}

\input{variablen}               % Variablen

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % Deutsche Silbentrennung usw.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Umlaute unter UTF8 nutzen
\usepackage{color}              % Paket für Textfarben
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin={4cm},rmargin={2cm},
tmargin={2.5cm},bmargin = {2.5cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}            % Mathematische Symbole
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}           % lädt das Paket zur Verwendung von Grafiken
\usepackage{float}              % lädt das Paket zur Verwendung von zusätzlichen Positionsbefehlen
\usepackage{wrapfig}            % Zur Positionierung von bildern
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literature}

\usepackage{listings}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
    language=Java,
    aboveskip=3mm,
    belowskip=3mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
    numbers=none,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    tabsize=3
}


\usepackage[automark, headsepline]{scrpage2}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadings
\clearscrplain
\lehead{\leftmark}              % Chapter auf gerader Seite links   
\lohead{\leftmark}              % Chapter auf ungerader Seite links 
\automark[section]{chapter} 
\rohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}   % Seitenzahl auf ungerader Seiten rechts oben
\rehead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}   % Seitenzahl auf gerader Seiten rechts oben
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}  %Chapter nicht als plain behandeln, neue Seite manuell


\begin{document}
\begin{wraptable}{l}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        tatsächlich & erkannt \\
        \hline
        28 & 25\\
        \hline
        28 & 25\\
        \hline
        30 & 30\\
        \hline
        28 & 26\\
        \hline
        28 & 27\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}   
    \caption{Vergleich der tatsächlichen mit den erkannten Schritten}\label{tab:schritte}
\end{wraptable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So the second and further lines should start at the left like "Tabelle 7.2:".
I think this behavior comes from some package, but my LaTeX know-how is too little to figure out from which one...

Comment: Welcome! Use the KOMA-Script command `\setcapindent{0pt}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please note, you always should add a [minimal **but working** example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Such a MWE should reproduce the problem without the need for any change. Currently your example needs an external file `variablen.tex` we do not have.

Comment: Off-Topic: You are using deprecated options `bibtotoc` and `liststotoc`. You should replace them according to the warning message they are producing. Otherwise several typographical improvements, that have been added to `scrbook` in the last decade, are deactivated. `scrpage2` is obsolete too. The successor is `scrlayer-scrpage`. Note also, that you do not have even pages, because you are using `oneside`. This means: `\lehead` and `\rehead` do nothing. `subfigure` is deprecated too. You should replace it by `subfig` or `subcaption`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\setcapindent{0pt}` to remove the indent of the second and further lines in captions.

In the following example I have removed all not needed packages and I have replaced the two deprecated class options and the deprecated package `scrpage2`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside,
  bibliography=totoc,% <- changed
  listof=totoc% <- changed
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\usepackage[automark, headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}% sets page style scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}% chapter on the inner margin
\ohead*{\pagemark}% page on the outer margin, also in page style plain
\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings}% if you relly want to do so ...

\setcapindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument

\begin{wraptable}{l}{0.3\textwidth}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        tatsächlich & erkannt \\
        \hline
        28 & 25\\
        \hline
        28 & 25\\
        \hline
        30 & 30\\
        \hline
        28 & 26\\
        \hline
        28 & 27\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}   
    \caption{Vergleich der tatsächlichen mit den erkannten Schritten}\label{tab:schritte}
\end{wraptable}
\Blindtext[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Additional remark: As @Schweinebacke already mentioned in a comment you should also replace the deprecated package `subfigure` by `subcaption`.